# I have a little issue with my table in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am inserting functions by javascript
`document.getElementById("table").innerHTML =wordloop();`
my wordloop function It looks like this.

```
set(z);
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML="<table class='table table-dark'><thead><tr><th>Polskie</th><th>Angielskie</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
for(var i=0;i<slowka.length;i++) {
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML+="<tr><td>"+words[i][0]+"</td><td> "+words[i][1]+"</td></tr>";
}
cument.getElementById("table").innerHTML+="</tbody></table>";
```

'set' its a function with array, nothing else.
In Effect only a header row work correctly.

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGeGt.png)

Comment: Where is the `words` array declared? Please update your post to satisfy the "complete" requirement of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you assign to `innerHTML`, it parses the HTML and creates a new DOM from it. If you leave an element unclosed, it has to close it to create a valid DOM. So your first assignment is creating a whole table. Then your loop adds `<tr>` elements *after* that table.

Instead of assigning to `innerHTML` in the loop, build a string with everything, and assign to `innerHTML` at the end.

```
var html = "<table class='table table-dark'><thead><tr><th>Polskie</th><th>Angielskie</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
for(var i=0;i<slowka.length;i++) {
    html+="<tr><td>"+words[i][0]+"</td><td> "+words[i][1]+"</td></tr>";
}
html+="</tbody></table>";
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = html;
```